# Show and Hide LI Item in Slide System

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a slide show ([CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/fyspG)):

```
<div class="slide">
  <ul class="data">
    <li id="C1" class="active">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/840x200">
    </li>
    <li id="C2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pipe">
    <li><a href="#C1" class="active"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#C2"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then I have the following JQuery:

```
function swap(name) {
  $('.slide .data .active').hide().removeClass('active');
  $('.slide .data [id = ' + name + ']').addClass('active').fadeIn("slow");
}
$(function () {
  $('.slide .data li:not(".active")').hide();
  $('.slide .pipe a').on("click", function () {
    swap($(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/, ''));
    return (false);
  });
});
```

At the moment I have 2 **problems**:

1. When I click the active circle the current slide flashes.
2. The active circle never changes even if the slide does.

Finally, can my JQuery code be improved?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified several different things to achieve what I think you were going for; here's an updated version of your [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeLwA).

Some of the main changes:

There was nothing in the code to target or change the active circles, and there was no way to easily distinguish one circle from another. I added `class="C1"` and `class="C2"` to the respective list items, and I targeted them in your swap function with the lines:

```
$('.slide .pipe a').removeClass('active');
$('.slide .pipe .' + name + ' a').addClass('active');
```

I achieved the fading effect by positioning the new item over top of the old item when fading it in through a combination of `position:absolute`, `z-index`, and adding/removing the `active` class.

Comment: Is it really necessary to add the C1 and C2 classes? The part of the HREF is the ID of the LI ... In your example it seems one is faded out while the other is fading in ... I would like to hide the active one and fade the other after it. You see in my example the transition is faster and there is no overlap of the slides.

Comment: Finally, could this be transformed in a plugin? The HTML structure will always be something like that ...

Comment: In my example, the new slide is fading in on top of the old slide--the old slide isn't fading out, so the transition is the same speed. But you can do it either way; here's an updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rDnAa/). The classes are not necessary, you can target the circles by their `href` attribute (as in the new CodePen I linked), but it's good practice to use classes or IDs for targeting elements. And yes, I'm sure this could be made into a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Just another question, if you don't mind ... Is it possible to change the slide to the next one automatically 10 seconds after the current slide being displayed?

Comment: Yep, look into [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) and [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearTimeout). Here's another updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tiHKs/).